# Role Management in Java Web Application

Tags: java, database, user-roles

I want to design Role Management in Java Web based Application i.e Admin can access all resources, Operator can access only a few resources, View only User cannot access any resources.

If I keep Role column in the User table, since Admin can perform all actions, so for all actions that Operator can perform I have to keep Admin check along with it. like below

```
if (role == Operator or **role== Admin**)
{

   do this....

}
```

otherwise, it will block the Admin for that operation.

Also, it will create a lot of scattered if else in case role type increases in future.

What is the best possible way to design it considering the future enhancement?

P.S. I don't want to use the framework like Spring Security.

Comment: Web applications are often developed within a framework that provides services through a container, eg. Tomcat.  Are you using one?  In such a case, authentication and authorization are typically implemented via  services.  For example, Java EE provides a simple form of declarative role-based authorization.

Comment: I am using Spring boot with Embedded Undertow Server

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `checkRole(role)` method into the `User` entity class, that checks whether the user has the specified role. It could return a `boolean`, or throw a specialized exception if the user has not the role.

### EDIT

To add range capabilities try something like this:

```
// Create role constants:
public final int ADMIN = 2;
public final int OPERATOR = 1;
public final int VIEW_ONLY = 0;

// Then implement the checkRole method:
public void checkRole(int role) {
  if (this.role < role)
    throw new MyAuthException("Insufficient rights");
}

// And in your action methods you can check for rights like this:
public .... Action(....) throws MyAuthException {
  loggedInUser.checkRole(OPERATOR);
  // Do whatever this action should do...
}
```

Comment: It wont help.
Let say /createUser can be done by Admin and Operator but not by View Only.
In that case my code will be (role == Operator or role== Admin) {
create User Allow }
else Not allowed..

Comment: If you map those roles into ordered values, like an `int`, you can do "greater than" checks, not just "equals" checks...

Comment: Yes that can be useful. Can you please elaborate a little.

Comment: Thanks that would help.Just one more thing how should I save role in the User table in the database. i.e an Integer number or Role name string which will be further mapped with Integer in a separate table or something else?

Comment: In the DB i would use an integer column.